# Jupyter notebook on remote VSCode session with multiprocessing gives error

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, vscode-extensions

I am connected to a remote server via the Remote - SSH extension on VSCode. When I am using an ipynb jupyter notebook file, and I try to Debug Cell the following simple cell,

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
pool = Pool(4)
```

I get the following error popup:
[image]

```
Invalid message: Session is already initialized
```

and simultaneously, a few of these messages on the bottom right of the VSCode window:
[image]

```
Failed to launch debugger for child process 16803
```

I believe this error is due to not being able to attach the debugger to the child processes, but I havent been able to resolve the issue. I tried setting "subProcess": true, in my launch.json, but that did not resolve anything. This error does not occur if I debug using 'Run and Debug' section of VSCode, nor does it happen if I use the pseudo notebook feature within .py files using #%% to create cells. It only happens in actual .ipynb files when debugging a cell.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Is it valid to use the pre-release version of `Jupyter Notebook` extension? This works well on my vscode. I think you can open an issue in [github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues) as well.

Comment: I have tried the prelease version of jupyter notebook as well as python extensions. I have also tried several older versions and even tried installing the manual vsix to see if there was an issue with that. Problem persists. Note that this ONLY happens when debugging a remote connection.

Comment: This is strange. According to this [article](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/12481#issuecomment-647274814), it seems that this problem should have been solved long ago. I think you can submit a bug in github.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Ill make my way over to their issues page!